# What are some unique ways to say "no data available"?

Tags: mobile, ios, error-message, data, social-media

What is a good message to put for "**No data available**"?, Currently I include something as below. Is it good? to be specific the posts are in timeline format.

**I Include Sad Face on top of the view:** Is this a good idea to even include the text style sad face? Or I should Include Vector of something?

## :'(

**The Message:**

> No post available, please refresh or increase your discovery search in
> settings or post one yourself.

**Refresh Button:** Should I include refresh icons or Tap button with Text?

### Tap to Refresh.

What Are some good ways and short ways that make users more active and not irritating them?

Comment: by timeline, do you mean an activity stream type of interface, like on facebook or aggregated news articles, or a chronological list of search results?

Comment: @ToniLeigh Yes, Exactly.

Comment: which one out of the two?

Comment: @ToniLeigh Facebook aggregated news

Answer (score 4):

The best way to show the message is in a simple, informal way with words that speak to the domain, rather than the technology or medium.

For instance, if this message is in response to a user searching posts for a specific subject, the message could be something like this:

> There aren't any conversations on this topic.

If you wanted to get cute, you could also let the domain influence your choice of graphic.  For instance, maybe a picture of someone in an empty room, looking awkward.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your audience, but if you're trying to make users more active and not irritate them... make them laugh. I love Spaceballs The Movie.
This is how you say it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, that particular message or smiley or any form of indication will depend upon the app and type of audience using it.

For instance,

In a game app, we could have a "Tap to refresh" text rather than this, we could have a text like "PULL, Rope of hope !!!" or "Pull the Rope" or "To continue... TAP IT"

So this way we could list down the message or even images to show case the best suitable medium of indicating something to the user.

Ain't found a shit mentioned in above post is a nice text for alert and also I liked your :( (sad face) as its good way to let user know that something went wrong.

At end, list down text/image as per your audience/app theme and find the one.